# How can I read certain characters from a .txt file and write them to a .csv file in Python?

Tags: python, csv

So I'm currently trying to use Python to create a neat and tidy .csv file from a .txt file. The first stage is to get some 8-digit numbers into one column called 'Number'. I've created the header and just need to put each number from each line into the column. What I want to know is, how do I tell Python to read the first eight characters of each line in the .txt file (which correspond to the number I'm looking for) and then write them to the .csv file? This is probably very simple but I'm only new to Python!

So far, I have something which looks like this:

```
with open(r'C:/Users/test1.txt') as rf:
    with open(r'C:/Users/test2.csv','w',newline='') as wf:
        outputDictWriter = csv.DictWriter(wf,['Number'])
        outputDictWriter.writeheader()
        writeLine = rf.read(8)
        for line in rf:
            wf.write(writeLine)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/test2.txt')
df.to_csv(r'C:/Users/test2.csv')
```

Here is how to read the first 8 characters of each line in a file and store them in a list:

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    lines = [line[:8] for line in f.readlines()]
```

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion :) I tried using Pandas, and although it did organise it a bit better than before it still isn't quite what I'm looking for. Essentially, I want it to look something like this:

`Numbers          Name
12345678         nameOfPerson
24681012         nameOfPerson2
36912151         nameOfPerson3

To:
Numbers          
12345678         
24681012         
36912151`

Comment: Sorry that formatted weirdly...but essentially, I just want to write the one column, removing information from the line which isn't the number

Comment: @PSwa916 I added it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to select digits with the charecter. Search for it
pattern  = re.searh(w*\d{8})

Answer (score 0):

Just go one step back and read again what you need:

> read the first eight characters of each line in the .txt file (which correspond to the number I'm looking for) and then write them to the .csv file

Now forget Python and explain what is to be done in pseudo code:

```
open txt file for reading
open csv file for writing (beware end of line is expected to be \r\n for a CSV file)
write the header to the csv file
loop reading the txt file 1 line at a time until end of file
    extract 8 first characters from  the line
    write them to the csv file, ended with a \r\n
close both files
```

Ok, time to convert above pseudo code to Python language:

```
with open('C:/Users/test1.txt') as rf, open('C:/Users/test2.csv', 'w', newline='\r\n') as wf:
    print('Number', file=wf)
    for line in rf:
        print(line.rstrip()[:8], file=wf)
```

Comment: This worked, exactly what I needed! That's amazing, thank you so much :D